# Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as python module and compiles with python 2.7 instead of python version in venv

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

Wsgi cannot compile the application with the python version in the venv instead always compiles with python 2.7. Here are my files please help

i am trying to deploy flask application , centos 7 using Apache 2.4.6 and mod-wsgi .

Target WSGI script '/home/nmapi/project/dir/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module is the error

here is my app.wsgi

```
activate_this = '/home/nmapi/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

## Expand Python classes path with your app's path

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
import sys
import logging
print(sys.path)
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"home/nmapi/project/dir")

from run import *
```

My virtual host config is

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

```
            #ServerName sample.server.com 
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            WSGIDaemonProcess score  threads=5 python-home=/home/nmapi:home/nmapi/deps/venv/lib/python3.5

            WSGIScriptAlias /test_wsgi 
            /home/nmapi/project/dir/datascience.wsgi
            <Directory /home/nmapi/project/dir/>
                    #WSGIProcessGroup score
                    #AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
                    #Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /home/nmapi/project/dir/static
            <Directory /home/nmapi/project/dir/static/>
                    WSGIProcessGroup score
                    #WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                    #AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
                    #Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog logs/error.log
            #ErrorLog /tmp/error.log
            LogLevel debug
            #CustomLog /tmp/access.log combined
            CustomLog logs/access.log combined
```

Comment: Are you using system mod_wsgi package? You likely are installing the Python 2.7 version of the mod_wsgi package. You can't force it to work with Python 3. You are better off uninstalling the system mod_wsgi package and using ``pip install`` method against the virtual environment for Python version you want to use. See https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/

Comment: Thanks for your response, ill try and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Graham Dumpleton, it worked for the test wsgi ,thanks for your help.But when i try running my app with two version on same server name i am getting 404 error.

Comment: Did i miss any configuration that need to be, also adding on to the above i have add output of 'mod_wsgi-express module-config' in the apache virtual host configuration.

Comment: How are you setting up config for both apps? If have more than one app, you should declare two daemon process groups and delegate each to their own. In that case, rather than use ``WSGIProcessGroup`` and ``WSGIApplicationGroup``, it is cleaner to use ``process-group=<name> application-group=%{GLOBAL}`` as arguments to ``WSGIScriptAlias``. Replace ``<name>`` with the actual name of the respective daemon process groups. The order of ``WSGIScriptAlias`` is important if both in same host. Put any for ``/`` last.